# Return multiple values in compactMap return

Tags: swift

Is it somehow possible to add multiple values in an compactMap return?

This is what i tried. It won't work because the return expects a String.

```
var array: [String] = ["This","is","just","an","example"]

var newArray: [String] = array.compactMap({ return [$0, "foo"] })

print(newArray)
```

I want an output array like: ["This","foo","is","foo","just","foo","an","foo","example","foo"]

But i dont want a solution for that specific example. I'm asking if it is possible to return multiple values in an compactMap and manipulate the count of it within the compactMap

Comment: Not very clear what you are trying to achieve. Include sample output.

Comment: @nayem i updated my question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Not sure how you want to manipulate the count within the closure. But to get the kind of output, you will need `flatMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good example where a wrong type annotation breaks the code.

The type of the mapped array is actually `[[String]]`

Basically don't annotate types the compiler can infer.

You you don't need `compactMap` as all types are non-optional

```
let array = ["This","is","just","an","example"]
let newArray = array.map({ return [$0, "foo"] })
print(newArray)
```

However to get `[String]` you have to use **`flatMap`**

```
let array = ["This","is","just","an","example"]
let newArray = array.flatMap({ return [$0, "foo"] })
print(newArray)
```

Comment: I want a [String] array. Thats exactly the purpose of my question. I know that the example doesnt produce a [String] array. The type annotation is there to to show what i want to get.

Comment: flatMap is deprecated

Comment: No it's not, not with this functionality.

Comment: Okay, sorry. Then your answer is perfectly valid for my question. In my case it gives: flatMap' is deprecated: Please use compactMap(_:) for the case where closure returns an optional value

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `flatMap` method:

```swift
let array = ["This","is","just","an","example"]
let newArray = array.flatMap({ return [$0, "foo"] })
print(newArray)
// ["This", "foo", "is", "foo", "just", "foo", "an", "foo", "example", "foo"]
```